# ClassLoader::getSystemResource returning null

Tags: kotlin

It used to work in the past, but I don't what happened in the middle, now it returns always `null`.

The file to read is in the project [root diretory](https://github.com/kotlin-graphics/imgui/blob/master/imgui.ini), which corresponds to the output of `Paths.get(".")`.

Note: function is top-level

I'm reading the `imgui.ini` file [here](http://fileLoadToLines(iniFilename))

`fileLoadToLines(iniFilename)`

where it's so [defined](https://github.com/kotlin-graphics/imgui/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/imgui/internal/helpers.kt#L153)

`fun fileLoadToLines(filename: String) = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(filename)?.use { it.bufferedReader().readLines() }`

Tried also the other `Thread.currentThread().contextClassLoader`, no success

What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project root directory is typically the default *current working directory*, but not necessarily on the classpath. That's why `Paths.get(".")` returns it, while the classloader doesn't find the file under it, because the latter goes by what's in the classpath.

It used to work probably because you had the project root added to the runtime classpath. The solution I would recommend is instead of using a classloader, just use the file system API in java.io to load it.